# Why doesn't the newly set property persist on jQuery object but it persists on the dom element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`elem` is the dom element with id dummy. `jElem` is the jquery object wrapped around `elem`.

`obj1` has `init` method which sets a property on the argument passed to it. Here, it creates a new property `prop` and sets `true` on it. `obj2` is also passed the same argument in its `init` method. `obj2` also has `showProp` method which prints the property set on the argument passed. Following is the code:

```js
let elem = document.querySelector("#dummy");

let obj1 = {
  init(item){
    item.prop = true;
  }
};
let obj2 = {
  init(item){
    this.item = item;
  },
  showProp(){
    console.log(this.item.prop);
  }
};
obj1.init($(elem));
obj2.init($(elem));
obj2.showProp(); //undefined

obj1.init(elem);
obj2.init(elem);
obj2.showProp(); //true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dummy">dummy</div>
```

My concern is: When `jElem` is passed in both the objects, the property on jElem is not persisted. But when dom element is passed itself(`elem`), the property persists. Why is that?

Comment: Both work for me using the code shown. Create a runnable [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. Can click on `<>` in question editor to create a stack snippet that runs right here in the page

Comment: I've converted your code to a snippet and added a dummy div.  Without the dummy div, you get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'prop' of null` which doesn't match your alleged `undefined` - as above, please edit the snippet to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: `.prop` is a jquery function. don't try to set it.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. I wrote in the answers section the answer to what the problem was. Both the init methods are passed 2 different objects and not the same object. Should we close this question or keep it so that others can learn from the mistake? lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so sorry about the misunderstanding. It was actually dumb of me. I didn't get sleep and was not able to debug properly. The problem was I was writing code as below:

```
let elem = document.querySelector("#dummy");

let obj1 = {
  init(item){
    item.prop = true;
  }
};
let obj2 = {
  init(item){
    this.item = item;
  },
  showProp(){
    console.log(this.item.prop);
  }
};
obj1.init($(elem));
obj2.init($(elem));
obj2.showProp(); //undefined

obj1.init(elem);
obj2.init(elem);
obj2.showProp(); //true
```

This is obviously as expected because I am creating a new jQuery object when passing to the function: `obj1.init($(elem))` and `obj2.init($(elem));`. Here, obviously both the `init` methods are passed 2 different objects and not the same object.